# Android studio import project window hangs

Tags: android, android-studio

I am following this tutorial :

```
https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples#if-youre-using-android-studio
```

But whenever I do import project I get following window and it hangs.

[image]

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Just for the records and to help anyone who faces this issue in future. My issue got resolved by simply restarting the windows.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered similar issue.  Please check the system Environment Variable of your PC, the JAVA_HOME path should be set correctly according to Java installed in your PC; something like this in my PC  "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172"

This resolved the issue for me.

Cheers!
Herbs

Answer (score 0):

you can go through the given link and u will get a correct direction on this. if u want to import an android studio project(not other IDE like eclipse..) , don't try to import just open it in android studio and Sync using gradle sync button. The link is only help to import other IDE project into android studio.

[Import projects in android studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html)

Comment: As mentioned in the link given by you : `From the Android Studio menu select File > New > Import Project. ` When I do this Android Studio hangs.

Comment: @nav_jan if you want to import eclipse project to your android studio or android studio project to android studio??

Comment: android studio project to android studio

Comment: Oh... ok then u don't want to import project, just go and open the project into android studio.